# Не работает Spinner | jQuery UI

Tags: javascript, ui, виджет

Есть интернет магазин в корзине заказов отображены все выбранные к покупке товары.

У каждого товара есть input c уникальным ID, для выбора количества.

При подключении Spinner | jQuery UI работает стилизация только у первого товара и только если я в js пропишу его ID

HTML:

```
<input class="form-control" id="10001" min="1" value="1">
```

атрибут ID у всех разный!

JS:

```
$("#10001").spinner();
```

Вопрос:

Как можно подставлять динамично id в JS чтоб стилизация input работала у всех товаров?

Answer (score 0):

```js
  $( function() {
    var spinner = $( ".spinner" ).spinner();
    
    $("#add").click(function(){
      $("body").append('<p><input class="spinner"></p>');
      $(".spinner").each(function(){
        $(this).spinner();
      });
    });
  } );
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Spinner - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="/resources/demos/external/jquery-mousewheel/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
<p>
  <label for="spinner">Select a value:</label>
  <input class="spinner">
</p>

<button id="add">add</button>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```